# Changing size/length of ndarray?

Tags: python, physics, numpy-ndarray

I have a projectile motion

```py
y0 = [0., 0., 15 * np.cos(alpha), 15 * np.sin(alpha)]
time = np.linspace(0, 5, num=10000)
res = ode.odeint(func, y0, time)
```

To remove negative values for `y-axis`, I use

```py
yy = np.delete(res[:, 1], np.where(res[:, 1] < 0)[0], axis=0)
```

But how to change

```py
res[:, 0] =     # xaxes
res[:, 2] =     # velocity x-direction
res[:, 3] =     # velocity y direction
```

to the same length/size array as `y-axis` after the change?

Comment: There is no way to directly do that. Should save the deleted index then delete it in the x array using that list of index.

Answer (score 0):

As @AerysS mentioned in the comments, you need to save the indices you want to remove:

```py
indices = np.where(res[:, 1] < 0)[0]
x_ = np.delete(res[:, 1], indices, axis=0)
y_ = np.delete(res[:, 2], indices, axis=0)
...
```